# Android. Font size too large to fit in cache. how to get cache size?

Tags: android, opengl-es, textview, android-custom-view

###### This is not duplicate, please read it first.

I've been recently working with a custom view that displays text and scales it with 'scaleX' and 'scaleY'. problem with this approach is that if you rotate the text to certain angles the quality text drawn on screen is extremely bad, so to counter that I set text size of TextPaint to a large number and scale it down to desired scale. problem with that approach is that if I enter an emoji inside that text then the emoji wouldn't render because of that large number that I set as text size but normal characters are rendering fine; and then in logcat says OpenGlRenderer: Font size too large to fit in cache

##### How can I retrieve size of the font cache to determine the size of text according to that?

###### Setting layer type to hardware or software did not solve the problem.

###### And I don't want to scale the text by increasing the text size (I scale it with 'scaleX' and 'scaleY')

Code for setting text size:

```
    context.resources.displayMetrics.run {
        textPaint.textSize = min(widthPixels, heightPixels) / density
    }
```

How I draw text:

```
canvas.drawText(text,0f /* x */, textBaseline /* y */, textPaint /* has large text size*/)
```

How I scale the text:

```
scaleX *= scaleFactor
scaleY *= scaleFactor
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, there's a bug in android that you have to call `Paint#getTextBounds()` after increasing and decreasing the size of text. So try calling that after you've adjusted the size.

Comment: @Darkman Thank you for your response, unfortunately it didn't work. I called this method after changing size, after scaling, on 'onMeasure' method but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at OpenGLRenderer documents, I came across few properties that defined the minimum size of font cache (small, medium, large) and I took the small font cache minimum height which was 256 pixels and set it as text size and it started to render emojis and text had good rendering quality too but I'm not sure if that's directly relatable to my problem, so I let the question to be open.

https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/renderer